# Rounded rectangle image selector shape is not showing properly in lolliop

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, shapes

I am trying to put selector on image which is rectangle it's working fine above lollipop but not in lollipop and lower version of it.

i used cardview with two images one with imageselector and one actual image.

anyone can guide me why it's not working properly!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item>
            <shape android:tint="@color/transparent">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="3dp"
                    android:color="@color/black" />

                <corners
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
                    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
                    android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:bottom="2dp"
            android:left="2dp"
            android:right="2dp"
            android:top="2dp">
            <shape android:tint="@color/transparent">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/white" />

                <corners
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
                    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
                    android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>





<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/image_selector_item_card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:clipToPadding="true">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_selector_item_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/border_selected"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/image_selector_selected_border"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Expected: 
[image]

In Lollipop: 
[image]

Comment: whats the the current output and whats the expected output?

Comment: this is current output and i want that border around imageview, let me attach other screenshot which is working in other device.

Comment: @Jayanth it's properly working in other device as you can see in expected image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this to below tested code

dummy.xml inside drawable

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        <stroke android:color="@color/black" android:width="3dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

and

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/image_selector_item_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/dummy">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_selector_item_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

let me know if it works

Comment: can i use ConstraintLayout istead of linear, will it work? i'm bound to use ConstraintLayout.

Comment: That's just a container layout you can use whichever layout you want.

Comment: Margin in Imageview is important

Comment: ok so problem is i can't change it from imageview to layout because some code is dependent on imageview example that image view work as selector of image in recyclerview so its visible and hide according selection.

Comment: put back the imageview with same id but dont give background

Comment: although i can change it's just view but i have to change my entire code if it's worth to change then i will.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190257/discussion-between-rucha-bhatt-joshi-and-jayanth).